# Flutter automaticaly open atached url on the 'ontap' event in ListTile

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem because when I attach the URL to each element on my list, on the first element it takes the URL and opens it automatically, so, whats work with it?

This is My container

```
        Container(
          height: 44.0,
          child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: _pageList(webpage, linkedin, twitter, github)),
        ),
```

This is the load of the list elements

```
List<Widget> _pageList(webpage, linkedin, twitter, github) {
  var listSkills = new List<ClipRRect>();
  if (webpage != null) listSkills.add(_createUrlElement(webpage, 'webpage'));
  if (linkedin != null) listSkills.add(_createUrlElement(linkedin, 'linkedin'));
  if (twitter != null) listSkills.add(_createUrlElement(twitter, 'twitter'));
  if (github != null) listSkills.add(_createUrlElement(github, 'github'));

  return listSkills;
}
```

This is the element creation. ... yessss, I know than there's better ways to do this, but, I just test all possibilities than I saw on net and it was the last code than I have, so, forgive me and don't kill me for this part of the code, jeje

```
ClipRRect _createUrlElement(webpage, icon) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
    child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        color: Colors.black26, //.gray.fromRGBO(52, 58, 64, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset(
            'assets/$icon.png',
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(''),
          title: Text(''),
          onTap: launcherUrl(webpage), // TODO: this open the url automatic
        )),
  );
}
```

I guess than this is enough to understand the problem, but, if you prefer you can check the repository

https://github.com/sgermosen/DominicanWhoCodes/blob/master/DominicanWhoCodes.Flutter/lib/providers/cardType1.dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reference a function but call it in the `onTap` handler.

Do this,

```
ClipRRect _createUrlElement(webpage, icon) {
  return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
    child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 60,
        color: Colors.black26, //.gray.fromRGBO(52, 58, 64, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset(
            'assets/$icon.png',
            width: 35,
            height: 35,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(''),
          title: Text(''),
          onTap: (){
             launcherUrl(webpage)
           }, 
        )),
  );
}
```

This should fix it.

Comment: definitely it fix it, :D